# How to change the base cases of a tribonacci sequence solved by matrix exponentation

Tags: matrices, fibonacci-numbers

So the base case of a Fibonacci sequence is the following matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} 
Which I understood as being:
\begin{bmatrix}F_2&F_1\\F_1&F_0\end{bmatrix} 
And that seems logical. But I don't really understand what each of the numbers in a tribonacci base case mean:
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}

I don't really understand what each of these numbers represent so if someone could help me, I would appreciate it. Also, I need to compute a tribonacci sequence where the base cases are not `t[0]=0, t[1]=0 and t[2]=1` (like in the above matrix), but `t[0]=1, t[1]=1 and t[2]=2` So how exactly could I implement that into the matrix that represents the base case? Do I just replace it like the following:
\begin{bmatrix}2&2&2\\2&1&1\\1&2&1\end{bmatrix}
But what if I would want to replace them with distinct numbers, say for example `t[0]=3, t[1]=5 and t[2]=8` ? Where would each of these numbers be placed in the matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}, \forall n \ge 2$ means that

$$\begin{bmatrix} F_{n} \\ F_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 
 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} F_{n-1} \\ F_{n-2} \end{bmatrix}$$

and the initial conditions are $F_0 = F_1 = 1$ so $\begin{bmatrix} F_{1} \\ F_{0} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Therefore iteration gives

$$\begin{bmatrix} F_{n} \\ F_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 
 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} F_{n-1} \\ F_{n-2} \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 
 & 0\end{bmatrix}^2\begin{bmatrix} F_{n-2} \\ F_{n-3} \end{bmatrix} = \cdots = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 
 & 0\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix} F_{1} \\ F_{0} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 
 & 0\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Similarly the Tribonacci numbers satisfy $T_n = T_{n-1} + T_{n-2} + T_{n-3}, \forall n \ge 3$ so

$$\begin{bmatrix} T_{n} \\ T_{n-1} \\ T_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 
 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} T_{n-1} \\ T_{n-2} \\ T_{n-3}\end{bmatrix}$$

Your initial conditions are $T_0 = 1$, $T_1 = 1$ and $T_2 = 2$ so $\begin{bmatrix} T_{2} \\ T_{1} \\ T_0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Therefore as above we get
$$\begin{bmatrix} T_{n} \\ T_{n-1} \\ T_{n-2}\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 
 \end{bmatrix}^{n-2}\begin{bmatrix} T_{2} \\ T_{1} \\ T_{0}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 
 \end{bmatrix}^{n-2}\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So I use the same "universal" base case and multiply it by itself n-2 times and then I multiply it with a matrix made by my custom base case, i.e. [2, 1, 1] ?

Comment: @BogdanVlad Not really, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 
 \end{bmatrix}$ has nothing to do with the base case, only the recursion $T_n = T_{n-1} + T_{n-2} + T_{n-3}$. What you wrote before that the Fibonacci matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix} F_2 & F_1 \\ F_1 & F_0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
is only a coincidence.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.